# Convert Compositing Node Group, to Shader Node Group

Tags: compositing-nodes, shader-nodes, conversion

I have a paid for Compositing Group Node that has identical Shader Node equivalents. I was hoping for a way to import it as Shader Group Node.

The node group has many connections between nodes. It would take me forever to reproduce it manually as you can see from the attached image.[image]

Comment: Simple answer is no. They might have same names and look the same, but they are different types of nodes. This applies to nodes in the _Shader Editor_, the _Compositor_ and also the _Geometry Nodes Editor_. Maybe someone could write a python script reading the nodes and connections to recreate the same with shader nodes, but I'm not the one... and this would require to "translate" the names of one type of node to the other type. And some are only similar, but not the same - the _Input > RGB_ node for example (but I'm not trying to figure out what you have there in this micro screenshot).

Comment: It only uses HSV Separate/Combine Color Ramps & Math Nodes. The python script option looks promising & I will look into it. Thank you.

Comment: Ah okay, seemingly editor independent nodes but still - they have the same names and same appearance, but internally they are different types. So if you are familiar with python scripting this could be the way. Please be so kind, when you find an answer don't just comment "got it" or so, you can post it here and accept it yourself, so future users might have a value from this as well.